# Python-requests and Meteor / MongoDB collectionapi update not working

Tags: python, mongodb, curl, meteor, python-requests

I'm trying to use Python Requests to send data to a Meteor application. I'm using the meteor-collectionapi to expose my collection.

I can use CURL to update my collection, like so:

```
curl -H "X-Auth-Token: 3243EEREFADfdsafkjghk432hljsfDS3" -X PUT -d "{\"\$set\":{\"level\":\"32\"}}" http://localhost:3000/collectionapi/containers/WjyuFkRdmq78qyzR7`
```

I'd like to perform the same command in Python using Requests. Here's the code I've put together:

```
import requests
import json
url = 'http://localhost:3000/collectionapi/containers/WjyuFkRdmq78qyzR7'
headers = {'X-Auth-Token': '3243EEREFADfdsafkjghk432hljsfDS3'}
payload = {'\$set':{'level':'43'}}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

When I run this the `$set` doesn't get passed properly and the POST doesn't work correctly (it creates a new object in the collection instead of updating the existing object). I've tried escaping it a variety of ways but nothing seems to work properly. If I don't escape the `$set` I get:

```
payload = {'$set':{'level':'38'}} 
{"error":"Error: key $set must not start with '$'"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your cURL command you're not doing a POST, you're doing a PUT.

Try changing your requests command to

```
r = requests.put(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

Comment: Somehow I missed that. >_<